# Upgrading Windows 8.1 to 8.1 Pro fails with "This key won't work. Check it and try again, or try a different key"

Tags: windows-update, windows-8.1

I can't seem to find a way to upgrade my laptop Windows 8.1 (64 bits) OS to Windows 8.1 Pro. I do have a key for the new version but when I input it in the Windows updater, it tells me:

> This key won't work. Check it and try again, or try a different key.

I'm using my MSDN and I know nobody used those keys.

To enter the key, I go to Control Panel - System, I see Windows Edition as 8.1. I click on "Get more features with a new edition of Windows" link, and in the popup "Add features to Windows 8.1" I select "I already have a product key".

Should I maybe just download the entire Wind 8.1 Pro ISO and run the install instead?
I would imagine the Windows Upgrade Tool would do it in a cleaner way.

Comment: Where are you entering the key? In the Anytime Upgrade area?

Comment: Control Panel - System, I see Windows Edition as 8.1. I click on "Get more features with a new edition of Windows" link, on the popup "Add features to Windows 8.1" I select on "I already have a product key"

Comment: Tried contacting Microsoft support?

Comment: The reason the key isn't working is because you cannot upgrade to just Windows 8.1 Professional your only upgrade path is the Windows 8.1 with Media Center.  You can try the full installer media method if you want but it won't work without a full reinstall.

Comment: @Ramhound no, I was also able to upgrade my Win8 Core to Pro by adding a Pro key in this dialog. So it works. I only used the cheep promo keys that MS sold during Win8 GA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For most of my clients, it wasn't working because by default the locale for everyone in MSDN downloads is UK, no matter where you live. If you search "Windows 8.1" by default the first result that shows up is the UK Edition, If your locale is the U.S., make sure to search for "Windows 8.1 (multiple editions) (English)" in your MSDN product keys.

Note:  If you're running Windows 8, you must use a Windows 8 Pro product key and not a Windows 8.1 Pro product key.  If you are running Windows 8.1, then you must use a Windows 8.1 Pro product key.

Comment: You don't now if that's the reason it wasn't working consider rewording your answer to reflect that fact

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: You can't know this was the authors problem

Comment: But then, @Ramhound, Stack Exchange sites are not intended to *only* help the OP? (I hope my edit suffices?)

Comment: You are correct answers should answer the question and help other people so quality generic or properly explained solution are acceptable

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8 search for `Windows Anytime Upgrade` or type `WindowsAnytimeUpgradeUI.exe` in the Run command

See 
http://www.petri.co.il/change-windows-8-1-edition-without-reinstalling.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your system after you apply the product key.  Your PC should now state Windows 8.1 Pro.

Note: The system is not doing an install.  It's just unlocking features the system is capable of having so its not really installing anything.